# Deleting a sequence of objects

Tags: r, naming-conventions

I have a bunch of data frames whose names are "yob.14", ..., "yob.60", based on year of birth. How do I delete them without having to `rm()` each one separately? I tried

```
rm(paste0("yob.",i))
```

but that got me an error message:

> ... must contain names or character strings"

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
rm(list=paste0("yob.",14:60))
```

EDIT: Using @baptiste's suggestion:

```
rm(list=Filter(exists, paste0("yob.", 14:60)))
```

In case some of the names generated do not reference existing dataframes.

Another option, using regexps (thanks @mnel):

```
rm(list=ls(pattern="^yob\\."))
```

Comment: Instead of `grep("^yob\\.", ls(), value=TRUE)`, perhaps `ls(pattern = '^yob\\.')`